# Within Terminal, `date` command outputs a curious prefix where it should'n

Tags: macos, terminal, command-line, zsh

I am using a Mac Mini running Lion (10.7.5) and zsh 4.3.12 (i386-apple-darwin11.0.1) with [oh-my-zsh](https://github.com/robbyrussell/oh-my-zsh) installed. In the Terminal.app I retrieve the UNIX timestamp using the following command

```
date +%s
```

It should print out a string of decimal digits - as the time of writing `1357294199`, however it prints `27m1357294199`. Notice the `27m`prefix. It stays constant aka. does not change with time.

I already tried the following but to no avail

- Closed and reopened the Terminal.app
- Restarted my computer

Why does the `date` command print this extra prefix and how do I get rid of it?

---

**Follow-ups** (Note: For the sake of simplicity outputs will use a constant timestamp)

- The command `date '+%s'` outputs `27m'1357294199`
- Command `/bin/echo Hello World` prints `Hello World`
- `type date` gives `date is /bin/date`
- `/bin/date +%s` prints `27m'1357294199`

Comment: What happens if you run it as `date '+%s`? And what does `/bin/echo Hello World` display? If they show the same problem, try `PS1= date +%s`.

Comment: patrix, please find the information you requested in the follow-up section as also more about the shell I use

Comment: Can you tell us the output of `type date`? And can you try `/bin/date +%s`?

Comment: Matteo, please find the output in follow-ups

Comment: Which version of oh-my-zsh are you using? The issue was solved several month ago: https://github.com/robbyrussell/oh-my-zsh/issues/57

Comment: Updating to the latest version of oh-my-zsh resolved the problem. Please write an answer so that I can accept it as also give you reputation points.

Comment: @lunohodov I updated my answer

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/6962/discussion-between-lunohodov-and-matteo)

Comment: Looks like a misplaced ANSI escape character

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue was due to a bug in oh-my-zsh:

1. The bug was fixed several months ago: update oh-my-zsh and the issue should be solved.
2. If for any reason you cannot update there is fix on StackOverflow (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12321564/date-command-with-zsh) but it involves the editing of `lib/termsupport.zsh`: remove the 12th line (warning I do not have oh-my-zsh installed and cannot check if the line number is really the correct one).